# OOP: How to Manipulate Objects Using ORM Techniques?

Tags: object-oriented, uml, class-design, class-diagram, relational-modelling

about those **objects** and **arraylists** inside the classes, derived from **one-to-many** relationships, using the **ORM** techniques, what's the best way to deal with them at the time of **setters** and **validation methods**? for instance: for me to save `PurchaseItem` inside `Purchase`, how and when do I chech that `PurchaseItem` is valid? what about if I save `PurchaseItem`, which is fulfilled but with an invalid `Product` (some empty attribute)? those classes can be found on the below diagrams.

my **DB diagram**:

[image]

my **class diagram**:
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as a general remark, it would've been nice if the two diagrams weren't ordered differently.

Comment: yes, Flater. you're right. my DB diagram was taken right from Access as it is. I did not have time to reproduce it in the same tool that I used to reproduce my class diagram. sorry.

Comment: I just meant dragging the boxes around, not remaking the diagram in another tool.

Comment: @Flater this DB diagram is fake because the original is in Portuguese. I must rearrange it keeping the English translation. you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common approach is *make it impossible to have an invalid object*.

That is, objects are constructed valid, and all the methods which mutate state of the object also leave it in a valid state, or return error, or throw.

When using this approach in a UI, the user-facing validation logic usually goes out with the objects, e.g. in the "controller" of MVC. That code would call the various set methods on the object and present any errors appropriately to the user.

Sometimes you need or want to persist objects which are not in a "valid" state, or you have multiple different definitions of "valid" to accomodate. In that case, I suggest a state machine. The object has a "state" property which can be valid or invalid (possibly also "unknown", meaning that the validation has not yet been run). The catch there is that any method which changes object state needs to explicitly set the validation state back to invalid or unknown. Or re-perform validation.

Comment: @Robert Harvey I like your idea. I'm new with oop concept in **VBA**, so, please, don't go crazy if I ask you noob things related to oop implementation. what I've done so far is to program the **getters/letters/setters** and a `DataValidation` method, which contains all the **business rules** and tests all the **model class properties**. for each violated rule, it **throws an exception** that can be caught in the **view class**. is that it how you'd also do to apply the business rules, considering that it is in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of strategies here, depending on how your ORM treats objects mapped from database tables. ORMs seem to treat objects in two ways. ORMs like Hibernate (Java) and NHibernate (.NET) allow you to map database tables directly to your business classes. Other ORMs, like Microsoft's Entity Framework, treat objects as Data Transfer Objects (basically property bags or POJOs in Java parlance).

When your ORM allows you to map directly to your business classes, each method and constructor should check for any and all business rules, which in OOP terminology we would call **class invariants**. Violations of these invariants can be handled in a number of ways that are transparent to the ORM. You could throw exceptions, return a "result" object that also tracks which rules were violated, or choose an intelligent default value or auto calculate values. This prevents an object from ever being in an invalid state.

ORMs that treat mapped classes as DTOs should not do any validation of data. These DTOs should have all public properties with public getters and setters. This architecture implies your business classes are not directly mapped to the database. Those business classes could be "services," like you see in many Java applications, or "commands" and "queries" if your application adheres to [Command-Query Responsibility Segratation (CQRS)](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). Some applications might have business classes just be regular classes with an intermediary mapping layer between your business objects and ORM DTOs.

Without knowing which ORM you are using, I can only provide this general information, however there is a common component no matter which data mapping philosophy your ORM uses. User input validations are a separate concern, and should be viewed as the necessary pre-checks required so you can call methods on your business logic layer without exceptions being thrown. There is no perfect solution here.

Business classes should throw exceptions in constructors and methods so you cannot violate business rules within the business logic layer. User input validation should occur in the controller or use case end of your architecture to ensure your business layer doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: this is a simple **POS software** developed in **VBA** using for my first time the oop concepts, so, please, don't go crazy if I ask you noob things related to oop implementation. I've programmed the **getters/letters/setters** and a `DataValidation` method, containing all the business rules, doing tests on all **model class** properties. it throws all the exceptions needed (no boolean), which can be caught in the **view class. how can I improve the implementation of business rules, considering that it is in VBA? or if I'm on the right way, please, let me know.